# half of the widgets are hidden in the Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout and i just change the edittext background for all the edittext widgets but for some reason i got the following screen.
as you can see in the second image i put the edittext bacground mistakely under the text view.
but when i fixed that and put the edittext background under the edit text with the hint please define min age, i got the first image and i dont understand why.
this is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewlayout">


        <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutFromTo">



            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Start"
                android:id="@+id/textViewCreateStart"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/row1" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCreateStart"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Start Date"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFromDate"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCreateStart"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonFromTime"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonFromTime"
                    android:background="#606060"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_weight="0.52" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Start Time"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFromTime"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="#606060"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonFromDate"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonEndTime"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonEndTime" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCreateEnd"
                android:id="@+id/createRow2">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="End Date"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEndDate"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCreateEnd"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonEndTime"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonEndTime"
                    android:background="#606060"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_weight="0.52" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="End Time"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEndTime"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonEndDate"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="#606060" />


            </TableRow>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="End"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCreateEnd"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/row1" />



        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recurring Event"

            android:id="@+id/checkBoxRecurring"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/createRow2"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxRecurring"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>



        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSportRadius"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutFromTo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">







        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#0091FF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/createRow4" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/createRow3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Sport"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSport"

                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Gender"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerSports"

                    android:id="@+id/textViewGender"
                    android:textStyle="bold"


                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="0.97" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/createRow4"

                android:layout_below="@+id/createRow3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerSports"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/createRow3"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="#606060"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerGender"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/createRow3"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:background="#606060"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </TableRow>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutSportRadius"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Participants:"
            android:id="@+id/textViewParticipants"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewMinAge"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewMinAge" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewParticipants"
            android:id="@+id/editTextMaxPaticipants"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:hint="Please Insert Number of Participants (2-30)" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Minimal Age:"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewMinAge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextMaxPaticipants"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"

            android:id="@+id/editTextMinAge"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMinAge"
            android:hint="Please define minimal age (14-40)"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


             <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Private Event"
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxPrivateEvent"
            android:checked="false"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonInviteUsers"
            android:text="Invite Users"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxPrivateEvent"
            android:background="#606060"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
             <View
                 android:id="@+id/divider4"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/buttonInviteUsers"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="6dp"
                 android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

             <ListView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/listViewInvitedusers"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
             </ListView>



         </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Location"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
                android:hint="Please insert event address"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLocation" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#0091FF"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLocation" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBtn"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <Button android:text="Create Event"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonSchedSave"
            android:background="#606060"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

after i made the change i got:

[image: After the change]

before i made the changes the screen was:

[image: Before the change]

and this is the custom background that i use:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:gradientRadius="100"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerY="50%"
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:type="radial"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="250dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#606060"
        />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, use @+id only for android:id attributes, for the other ones like android:layout_below... use @id/desired_id.

The plus sign (+) indicates to Android that this is a new resource name.